# EditingStyle - Remove cell and item in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, editing

I have created an array

`var subjectsData = [ Subject(name: "Investments", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Statistics", semester: 1), Subject(name: "Studium Universale", semester: 2) ]`

and a tableView

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SubjectCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubjectCell

    let subject = subjects[indexPath.row] as Subject
    let Semester = "\(subject.semester)"

    cell.nameLabel.text = subject.name

    cell.semesterLabel.text = "Semester"

    cell.semesterNumberLabel.text = Semester

    return cell
}
```

with `var subjects: [Subject] = subjectsData`.

I now tried to create an editing function in order to delete cells/rows and, thus, also the according item in the array.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        subjectsData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

To me the code looks logical and functioning, though when running the app crashes whenever I try to delete a row/cell and I receive the error:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Whenever I delete a row/cell, the according item in the array should be removed as well but if I understand the error correctly, the array does not seem to update/ remove the item?

I would be thankful if anybody had an idea why this error occurs and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I changed `subjectsData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`to this editingStyle code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        subjects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

since I said `var subjects: [Subject] = subjectsData`.

I don't know why exactly this took care of the error but now the app no longer crashes, when I try to delete something.